# Matplotlib Legend colors change when changing legend labels

Tags: python, matplotlib, colors, legend

I don't understand what I am doing wrong here. I want to change 0 and 1 in the legend to "zero" and "one" but somehow this changes colour in the legend as well.

This is how I get to the first picture:

```
sns.scatterplot(ax = axes, data = data_pcoa, x = "Coordinate 0", 
                y = "Coordinate 1", hue = "Number", palette = ["orange", "blue"])
axes.set(xlabel = "1st PCo", ylabel = "2nd PCo")
axes.legend()
```

[image: Plot 1]

This is how I get to the second picture:

```
sns.scatterplot(ax = axes, data = data_pcoa, x = "Coordinate 0", 
                y = "Coordinate 1", hue = "Number", palette = ["orange", "blue"])
axes.set(xlabel = "1st PCo", ylabel = "2nd PCo")
axes.legend(labels = ['zero', 'one'])
```

[image: Plot 2]

As you can see, in the second picture the legend titles have changed but the colours no longer match those of the plot.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I solved the problem by creating a custom legend. This is not very elegant but it does the job. It is weird though, because when I use the `axes.legend(labels = ["zero", "one"]` on a similar dataset it does work. Anyhow, this solved my problem (but I would love to know a more elegant solution):

```
legend_elements = [Line2D([0], [0], color = 'w', markerfacecolor = 'b', marker = 'o', label='one',  markersize=8),
                   Line2D([0], [0], color = 'w', markerfacecolor = 'orange',  marker='o', label='zero', markersize=8)]
```

Answer (score 1):

This works for me and it's a bit cleaner

```
handles, labels = ax.get_legend_handles_labels()
labels = ["zero", "one"]
ax.legend(handles, labels)
```

Answer (score 0):

From what i understood you need custom label name in the `scatterplot`.

Here is small example which answer your question.

```py
import seaborn as sns
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
tips = sns.load_dataset("tips")

g = sns.lmplot(
    x="total_bill", 
    y="tip", 
    hue="smoker", 
    data=tips,  
    legend=False
)

plt.legend(title='My Title', loc='upper left', labels=['Zero', 'One'])
plt.show(g)
```

[image]

**Another Method:**

```py
sns.scatterplot(data = tips, x = "total_bill", 
                y = "tip", hue = "smoker", palette = ["orange", "blue"])
ax = plt.gca()
ax.set(xlabel = "1st PCo", ylabel = "2nd PCo")
ax.legend(labels = ['zero', 'one'])
```

[image]

Comment: Hi Jay,

Thank you very much for your reply. I edited my post, since I tried that already and unfortunately didn't work.

Comment: What do you mean by not working ? `Seaborn` is technically wrapper on `matplotlib`. I had also put another method in my answer.